# Three js + open layers + d3

Tags: d3.js, three.js

I'm trying to create a globe where I can zoom, rotate, and interact with.
I need to highlight countries on hover and I have special locations with markers (like google maps). How can i achieve this ? Three JS, d3, open layers, Planetary.js. Any tips ?
I have a full working globe in Three JS only. But I need to map (x, y, z) coordinates to Lat/Lon pairs. You guys know what's the best way to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: it's a huge chunk so far. I could put it on a js fiddle but it's not worth. I just need to know if there's any webgl engineers out there who could point me on the right direction...

Comment: Check this http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5994804, the zoom is not included but you may rework the code to have a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise d3.js as a framework to use your map.

Here is a page where you'll find a demo and code to use a zoom on a map :
http://bl.ocks.org/marcneuwirth/2865882

And here is a globe demo and code where you may select countries and so on :
http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5994804

I wouldn't use the other framework/libraries that you mentioned, not because that are worse but because I'm working usually on a virtual machine and no graphic card installed and that webgl is just a pain on such machines. d3.js is working smoothly compared to the other solutions.

Comment: awesome. I appreciate your help. Thanks :)